# How to make page switcher in React/Vite project with 5 pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vite

i'm working on restaurant website project, I'm trying copying https://www.wix.com/demone2/halal-food-restauran, everything was good but I have problem after making 3 pages,i can't make switching between them,i think it's better make them 'display:none;' first, and after pressing buttons make display:flex;
I have separated parts, header,footer and other 5 pages that are switches by buttons

`import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Slide from './components/slider'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFacebook, faInstagram, faFontAwesome } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

import img1 from './assets/f1.png'
import img2 from './assets/f2.png'
import img3 from './assets/f3.png'
import logo from './assets/logo.png'
import line from './assets/a2.png'
import insta from './assets/insta.png'
import face from './assets/facebook.png'
import book from './assets/booking1.png'

export default function Header() {
const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");

```
const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
};

return(
    <section className='part1'>
        <div className='restaurant-header'>

            <h1 className='title'>HopeLake</h1>
            <div className='top-sec'>
                <ul className='top-icons'>       
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} className='icons'/>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} className='icons'/>
                </ul>
                <ul className='top-list'>
                    <li value={'App-home'}>HOME</li>
                    <li value={'App-about'}>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>MENU</li>
                    <li>ORDER</li>
                    <li>CONTACT</li>
                </ul>
                <button className='log-in'>Log In</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
)
```

}`

and my App,jsx

import './App.css';
import {useState} from 'react';

import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer'

import Home from './home'
import About from './about'

function App() {
return (

```
  <Home/>
  <About/>

  <Footer/>
</div>
```

);
}

export default App;

You can help with my code or just give example but its important to do it like here https://www.wix.com/demone2/halal-food-restauran

You can help with my code or just give example but its important to do it like here https://www.wix.com/demone2/halal-food-restauran

Comment: Sounds like you need a [router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main).

Comment: what is that and how It can help me?can you give me example

Comment: It's a router - it allows you to route your app to particular pages. You should read the documentation.

Comment: I read it, but its not smooth like in link above, do you have any other ideas?